# Model training with tf.data.Dataset raises shape error; why?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I feel like I am following this Keras [training guide](https://keras.io/guides/training_with_built_in_methods/#training-amp-evaluation-from-tfdata-datasets) almost verbatim. I'm trying to use a tf.data.Dataset to train my model. Doing so raises an error involving the shape of the dataset; this error is not raised if I pass numpy arrays or pd.DataFrames.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv').astype('int32')
dev_df = dataframe.sample(n=3000, random_state=1)
train_df = dataframe.drop(dev_df.index)

## I also ran the following with to_numpy() to make sure it's not an issue with
## dataframes.
X_train = train_df.drop('label', axis=1)
y_train = train_df['label']

## This section follows the guide linked above, as far as I can tell.
## 
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_ds.batch(128)
train_ds
```

The output at this point is `<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((784,), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>`. Everything looks okay. I contruct a simple model for the data:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784))
x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs ,outputs=outputs, name='simple_model')
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer="adam", 
                loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="acc")],
            )

## This is where the error occurs:
model.fit(train_ds)

## if we comment that out, it will run as expected with this:
#model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I run the cell, I get a warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 784) for input Tensor("input_7:0", shape=(None, 784), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (784, 1).
```

and then a long error message that ends

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_18 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [784, 1]
```

Now, normally, I would be like "Well, duh, the shapes don't align." But my question is: (1) why and (2) how do I construct a tf.data.Dataset that I can pass for fitting? I am following the guide (linked above) almost verbatim and don't see any discrepancies in creating the Dataset object. It seems like the .fit call isn't correctly dividing the data from the labels (The data should be of shape 784, not (784,1), and the 1 seems like it's the label column.

Comment: Try `train_ds = train_ds.batch(128)`

Comment: Oh my. How did I miss that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments by Nicolas Gervais, this is mistaken:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
## the next line returns a batched set, it does not set a batch size for the set.
train_ds.batch(128)
```

It will work correctly if we instead write:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
## we assign a batched dataset to the variable...
train_ds = train_ds.batch(128)
```